# "Manually" generating a PWM signal

Tags: led, pwm, analogwrite

I've been trying, just out of curiosity, to write my own function that generates a PWM signal, just like `analogWrite()`, and to make it light up an LED. Here's my attempt so far:

```
const int pin = 3;
int cycle = 2; // analogWrite() outputs a 498 Hz signal, so each cycle has approximately 2ms

int duty = 0.5; // for a 50% duty cycle

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pin,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(pin,HIGH);
  delay(cycle*duty);
  digitalWrite(pin,LOW);
  delay(cycle*(1-duty));
}
```

The LED does light up, but very dimly, as shown below:

[image: LED brightness with my code]

However, when using `analogWrite()` with a 50% duty cycle to achieve the same result, the LED shines much brighter:

[image: LED brightness with analogWrite(pin,128)]

Is there something wrong with my code, or is there a special reason why more power is dissipated with `analogWrite()`?

Comment: have you tried different values in `cycle`?

Comment: I've just tried that, and indeed the brightness increases as the cycle values get smaller. However, I had to use cycle values as low as 2 microseconds in order to get a brightness comparable to the one provided by `analogWrite()`. I can't really understand why, though, so I'd really appreciate it if you could provide some clarification. :)

Comment: i do not know ... i suspect that the signal waveform is not what you and I expect it to be ... only way to check is to put a scope or a logic analyzer on the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to review your code and also the capabilities of the Arduino UNO.

- `int` declares an integer.  So `int duty = 0.5;` is going to get rounded to either 0 1.
- `delay(0);` also will not work.  The instruction will simply get skipped. Likely the reason why you get a brighter LED. Try to use `delayMicroseconds();` if you need shorter time but the minimum delay you can have is 4 us for Arduino UNO.
- If you are using times as short as 2 us, then from the above comment the `delayMicroseconds();` function is not going to be sufficient.  Also, you should consider the loop overhead, which will be a few microseconds.

All in all this is not a great method.  If you do want to create your own PWM signals, it is much better to use the hardware timers.  For example [this tutorial on the Arduino website.](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer1/)  You should also be able to find posts about hardware timers on Arduino SE.